# Selecting a single row in the same table/view if a query returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have the following view in my SQL database, which selects data from a Transaction table and a Customer table:

```
+-------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| RowNo |   Name    |        Date         | Amount |
+-------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
|     1 | Customer1 | 2018-11-10 01:00:00 | 55.49  |
|     2 | Customer2 | 2018-11-10 02:00:00 | 58.15  |
|     3 | Customer3 | 2018-11-10 03:00:00 | 79.15  |
|     4 | Customer1 | 2018-11-11 04:00:00 | 41.89  |
|     5 | Customer2 | 2018-11-11 05:00:00 | 5.15   |
|     6 | Customer3 | 2018-11-11 06:00:00 | 35.17  |
|     7 | Customer1 | 2018-11-12 07:00:00 | 43.78  |
|     8 | Customer1 | 2018-11-12 08:00:00 | 93.78  |
|     9 | Customer2 | 2018-11-12 09:00:00 | 80.74  |
+-------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
```

I need an SQL query that will return all a customer's transactions for a given day (easy enough), but then if a customer had no transactions on the given day, the query must return the customer's most recent transaction.

Edit:

The view is as follows:

```
Create view vwReport as
Select c.Name, t.Date, t.Amount 
from Transaction t
inner join Customer c on c.Id = t.CustomerId
```

And then to get the data I just do a select from the view:

```
Select * from 
vwReport r
where r.Date between '2018-11-10 00:00:00' and '2018-11-11 00:00:00'
```

So, to clarify, I need one query that returns all the customer transactions for a day, and included in that results set is the last transaction of any customers who don't have a transaction on that day. So, in the table above, running the query for 2018-11-12, should return row 7, 8 and 9, as well as row 6 for Customer3 that did not have a transaction on the 12th.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It'd be great to see your existing query so that it's easier to understand how to modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your existing query and `UNION ALL` it with a "most recent transaction query" for everyone who doesn't have a transaction in that range.

```
with found as
( 
    select c.Id, c.Name, t.Date, t.Amount 
    from Transaction t
    inner join Customer c on c.Id = t.CustomerId
    where Date between '2018-11-10 00:00:00' and '2018-11-11 00:00:00' 
)
with unfound as
(
    select c.Id, c.Name, t.Date, t.Amount, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY CAST(Date AS DATE) DESC) AS row
    from Transaction t
    inner join Customer c on c.Id = t.CustomerId
    WHERE Date < '2018-11-10 00:00:00'
)
select Name, Date, Amount 
from found
union all
select Name, Date, Amount 
from unfound
where Id not in ( select Id from found ) and row = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're interested in selecting multiple rows with ties, you could use the `RANK()` function to find all rows *ranked* by date descending:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY CAST(Date AS DATE) DESC) AS rn
    FROM txntbl
    WHERE CAST(Date AS DATE) <= '2018-11-12'
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e8b4f7c94fcc80d15f8955304ce66a7)

Comment: Thanks. This only returns one record per customer. If a customer has many transactions on a given day, it must return all of them. If a customer has no transactions, it must return just their most recent.

Comment: Use rank() Instead of row_number() (I am assuming Date is DATE not DATETIME). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Just `CAST( AS DATE)` a couple of times. See revised answer.

Comment: you have 2 problems. You should handle this via CTE and inserting each result set into temp table or variable and joining the 2 result sets back via a Union. Depending on the size of your data you may have to use index on your temp table(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from transactions t2
                where t2.name = t.name and
                      t2.date <= @date
               );
```

Note:  This only returns customers who had a transaction on or before the date in question.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information available from the question, the following presents a solution using a join as opposed to a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*
from
    vwReport t1 inner join
    (
        select t2.name, max(t2.date) as mdate
        from vwReport t2
        group by t2.name
    ) t3
    on t1.name = t3.name and t1.date = t3.mdate
where
    t1.date <= @date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION for the last date transactions only if there are no transactions for the given dates (`BETWEEN '2018-11-10 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-11 00:00:00'`):

```
SELECT * FROM vwReport r
WHERE (r.Date BETWEEN '2018-11-10 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-11 00:00:00')
AND (r.Name = @name)
UNION
SELECT * FROM vwReport r
WHERE (r.Date = (SELECT MAX(r.Date) FROM vwReport r WHERE r.Name = @name))
AND (r.Name = @name)
AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vwReport r 
    WHERE (r.Date BETWEEN '2018-11-10 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-11 00:00:00') 
    AND (r.Name = @name)) = 0)
```